# Submitting Textarea on enter with Ajax and then rendering partial without refreshing whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Currently I am trying to make a comment post without the submit button through JS and Ajax and it works.

**The issue** is when the post is submitted, the page reloads to the `/post/:id/comment` page and I would like it to render the partial rather than refresh the whole page or take me to a different page. I am unfamiliar with JS, any help would be much appreciated!

This is what I am working with:

**JS for posting with enter**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   
$(function(){
    $('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
           var frm = this.form.submit(); 
            $.ajax({
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                complete: function(){
                    frm.submit(); 
                },
                dataType: json
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Comment Form**

```
<div class="CommentField">
<%= form_for ([micropost, @comment]), :remote => true do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content, :class => "CommentText", :placeholder => "Write a Comment..." %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

**Comment HTML**

```
<div class='UserCommentContainer'>
<div class='UserPicture'>
<%= image_tag comment.user.avatar.url(:bit), :class =>"PP" %>
</div>
<div class='UserComment'>
<div class='UserName sm'>
<%= link_to comment.user.name, user_path(comment.user) %>
</div>
<div class='UserCommentText'>
<%= comment.content %>
</div>
<div class='UserCommentDate'>
<%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the `<form>` have an `action` attribute?

Comment: @NickBeranek Yes, when it is in HTML form on the web page there is an action attribute which is the `post/:id/comment`

Answer (score 1):

you need something that can be resolved using a URL, so a partial won't do. You should set up a page for this function to call, and call it

Comment: Sorry if this sounds "dumb" but I am unsure what you mean

Comment: AJAx needs to get content from a URL, so you need to have a view file to do this

Answer (score 1):

okay let's try this again...

I think your looking for AJAX that looks more like this:

```
$('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var myTextArea = this,
            frm = this.form;

        this.disabled = true;           

        $.ajax({
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            complete: function(){
               $('<div>', { text: myTextArea.value }).appendTo('body');
               myTextArea.value = '';
               myTextArea.disabled = false;
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
});
```

you see how in the complete method we are just appending the contents of the `<textarea>` to the body... you probably have a container you want to put that in, but this is called "client side rendering" meaning that you are building the DOM (or changing it) on the client side instead of the server... hope this helps -ck

***----- edit -----***

I should make note that you probably want to be doing something more like: `.appendTo('#container')` where you have a `<div id="container">` somewhere on the page, and I am sure the comment needs more formatting and what not...

see if this demo helps you with the idea: http://jsbin.com/uruzul/edit#javascript,html,live

***----- more edit -----***

I also think to do this correctly you are going to have to "make use" of the AJAX return, and I didn't include this initially because it didn't seem like you had any concept of it in your code, but after seeing your comment HTML... you are going to need your server to return a JSON object that looks like:

```
{ 
    "userImage": "pictureUrl/image.jpg", 
    "userName": "user name here", 
    "userLink": "link/to/user/page", 
    "date": "3/5/2012", 
    "comment": "the text of the comment" 
}
```

and then instead of using `complete` you want to start using `success` and `error` see documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/   **like this:**

```
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('comment submit failed!\n\n' + textStatus);
            },

            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
               var cnt = $('<div>')
                .addClass('UserCommentContainer')
                .appendTo('.CommentContainer');

              $('<div>')
                .addClass('UserPicture')
                .appendTo(cnt)
                .append($('<img>', { src: data.userImage, 'class': 'pp' }));

              cnt = $('<div>')
                  .addClass('UserComment')
                  .appendTo(cnt);

              $('<div>')
                .addClass('UserName sm')
                .appendTo(cnt)
                .append($('<a>', { href: data.userLink, text: data.userName }));

              $('<div>')
                .addClass('UserCommentText')
                .appendTo(cnt)
                .text(data.comment);

              $('<div>')
                .addClass('UserCommentDate')
                .appendTo(cnt)
                .append(data.date);

               myTextArea.value = '';
            },

            complete: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
               myTextArea.disabled = false;
            },
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing :/ Taking me to a `post/:id/comment` rather than refreshing the partial

Comment: Yeah the thing is I don't want it to take me to another page but the reload is doing that and instead of reloading the whole page or taking me to a new page is there a way to refresh just the partial to have the comment post automatically? Something along the lines of facebook's comment system

Comment: @FrostedFlakes check it out now, I think we are now on the same page

Comment: where it says `body` you want me to insert the container of the comments I assume?

Comment: @FrostedFlakes yes you need to edit that to make it "render" correctly but that's the general idea... i just gave you that so you could understand as I have no idea what your HTML looks like... i just added a url also...

Comment: Sorry for the barage of questions but the code above is just disabling my textarea and not storing the post nor posting the post, here is my HTML for the comment section also instead of body I inserted the `<div id="comment">` you'll see here: http://pastebin.com/ms7DSbyi

Comment: @FrostedFlakes it's okay, you are getting into the area where the web starts to get a little hairy, AJAX is kind of a pain until you find that winning formula of server/client and then you'll be able to crank this stuff out, look at what I posted above and see if that helps any... and don't forget to check your javascript console for any errors! good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. Your code is telling the form to submit...before the ajsax occurs. I suspect you are not returning json in response so may still have an issue with the "json" dataType being incorrect

```
$(function(){
    $('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
           var frm = $(this).closest('form'); 
            $.ajax({
                url: frm.attr('action'),
                data: frm.serialize(),
                complete: function(){
                    /*frm.submit();*/ 

                    window.location='url/you/want';
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: Instead of a specific url, can't I make this just post a new comment without refreshing the whole page? Like facebooks comment system?

Comment: I think you need to reassess the logic behind the whole thing.... unusual to make an ajax call every time a letter is enetered. Norm would be use a "submit comment" button.

Comment: mmm the logic, the thing is I would like the comment system to be able to post with a button so that when a user presses enter the post is posted as well as the post appears on the page without the whole page refreshing

Comment: then you need a form, a submit handler for form to handle ajax, and a sucess callback to input the comment in page.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, to my understanding, I would need another form to submit this form to handle the ajax?

Comment: I can't help without seeing some of your source markup...not the server code

Comment: best thing would be real html in a demo at jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

You should find some general Ajax guide for Rails, I'd recommend a free [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript). There is an example with a search form that does not reload the whole page on submit, your case is very similar. Also I suggest to implement this with a submit button first.

Comment: I have implemented the submit button first but the more I thought about it I would like to have it like `facebook` style with the commenting system, and thank you for the advice