# Post data from textarea to DIV tag in same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Hi I tried to post data from my Text Area to DIV tag. But its not working. Please help me out. Following is my code

```
<html>

<head>

<script>

function load()
{
var a=document.getElementById('txtarea').value;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
xmlhttp.open("POST","one.php"+a,true);
xmlhttp.send(); 
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<textarea id='txtarea'>
    default
</textarea>
<div name="myDiv" id="myDiv">
    In Div Tag
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

one.php

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

In the above html file i am trying to get the value of one.php and also the text in textarea. But i am unable to get the value in text area.The xmlhttp.open("POST","one.php"+a,true); Here i am doing +a to attach the value of the textarea but it is not being attached,please help with some solution

Comment: you are looking for javascript solution or jquery solution for this.

Comment: U have to try this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569186/submitting-textarea-on-enter-with-ajax-and-then-rendering-partial-without-refres

Comment: i just want a demo example wherein the user can transfer the value from textarea into a div tag on same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL is not properly constructed.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET",""one.php?YourQueryString="+a,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET",""one.php?YourQueryString="+a,true);
    xmlhttp.send();   This is nt working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Although your query doesn't make much sense, but In xmlhttp.open(), you need a proper url to send the request. You can add the textarea value as a query parameter, and then try:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","one.php?val="+a,true);
```

But I don't see your AJAX syntax to be correct

Comment: xmlhttp.open("POST","one.php?val="+a,true); doesnt work. And my question is simple post data of textarea into DIV using ajax.